# How do I get Buttons to adapt to any screen size in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

So I want to have an ImageView, which is a speechbubble and a button which is a penguin inside my activity.
The penguinbutton should be on the bottom right and the speechbubble ImageView a little bit to the left above the penguin.
It works fine while I set all the widhts and heights to a fixed value but it all resizes once I open it on another device.
my problem is that I cannot find any way to make those elements adapt to the different screen sizes the way I want them to.
Down below is some code which does resize them on every device, but it resizes it 50/50, so the ImageView takes up 50% of the upper screen while the button takes up 50% of the lower screen.
I dont know how to keep them in a certain position while still resizing on different screens.
Any help is welcome.

```
   <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ein_hintergrund2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/speechbubble"
        android:id="@+id/klick_textView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:background="@drawable/pinguin"/> </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is kind of complicated I would go with different layouts base on different screen sizes. Or if it is landscape etc.

I would recommend to have a look on [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `ConstraintLayout` it'll help you in most of your cases to have a similar layout depending on the device/screen.

You can find a [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0) to help you go though it.